Auf dem Gesicht landen/auf das Gesicht landen: korrekte Wechselpräposition bei einem Verb der Bewegung
Ich habe heute einen Muttersprachler gehört, der sagte

Eine Fliege ist auf meinem Gesicht gelandet.

Ich hätte gedacht, dass das richtige

Eine Fliege ist auf mein Gesicht gelandet.

wäre, wenn auch nur deswegen, weil „landen" ein Verb der Bewegung ist, und so, wie bei

Ich fahre heute in die Stadt.

eher den Akkusativ verlangt. Anscheinend nicht. Aber wieso?

Leider gibt es dafür keine Regel. Man muss sich für jedes Verb merken, ob es eine Richtung oder einen Ort erwartet. Das wichtigste Beispiel dafür sind die Verben kommen und ankommen.

Meine Frau kommt zum Bahnhof, wenn mein Zug am Bahnhof ankommt.

Sowohl meine Frau als auch mein Zug bewegen sich in Richtung des Bahnhofs. Allein der Unterschied zwischen diesen beiden auch noch verwandten Verben bewirkt, dass mit zum Bahnhof eine Richtung benötigt wird, mit am Bahnhof hingegen ein Ort.

Ich verstehe die Wahl der Beispiele nicht, denn auch zum Bahnhof (= zu dem Bahnhof) steht ja im Dativ und beschreibt damit eigentlich einen Ort.

Nein, das Merkmal "Ort" führt bei Wechselpräpositionen dazu, dass Dativ erscheint – es ist nicht so, dass "Dativ" als solcher immer die Bedeutung "Ort" ergeben würde. Erstens, weil wie gesagt die Logik der Sache andersrum ist, zweitens, weil "zu" keine Wechselpräposition ist.

Das Flugzeug landet auf dem Flughafen. Der Flughafen ist der Ort, wo die Landung passiert, und der Ort ändert sich nicht. Man betrachtet den Flughafen als Ganzes, und beschreibt was dort passiert.
Das ist ähnlich wie "Ich jogge/laufe im Park". Da bewege ich mich auch, aber das passiert innerhalb des Parks. Aber: "Ich laufe in den Park" - Ich beginne, schon bei Verlassen des Hauses zu joggen, und jogge von daheim bis zum Park, und dann in den Park hinein.
UPDATE
Mir ist gerade aufgefallen, dass mein vorheriger Kommentarm auch wenn er in sich stimmig ist, an der Frage völlig vorbeigeht. Es gibt ja einen fundamentalen Unterschied zwischen einem auf einem Flugplatz landenden Flugzeug und einem auf dem Gesicht landenden Menschen. Das Flugzeug nähert sich zwar bei der Landung dem Flughafen, doch der Mensch nähert sich NICHT bei seiner Landung dem Gesicht.
Eine Analogie wäre wohl eher, wenn man es mit
Das Flugzeug landet auf seinem Hauptfahrwerk

vergleicht. Anders ausgedrückt: Wenn das Flugzeug landet, berührt das Haupfahrzeug als erstes den Boden.
Ähnliche Fälle:
Ich hüpfe auf einem Bein.
Ich schleiche auf meinen Zehenspitzen durchs Zimmer.


Danke.  Das ist genau das, was ich meinte: in den Park (Richtung), im dem Park (Ort).  Dementsprechend: "landen auf" scheint mir eine Richtung zu sein, also hätte ich den Akkusativ erwartert.  Ich schäzte dass es so ist, wie @Janka oben erwähnt, dass man es sich einfach merken muss.

Ich denke eher, dass wir beim Landen des Flugzeugs nicht an eine Richtung denken. Das ist eher wie bei "Ich parke auf DEM Parkplatz". Vom Gefühl her sind wir schon dort (Flughafen, Parkplatz) und müssen dort nur mehr die Aktion (landen/parken) durchführen. Daher dann auch "auf dem Gesicht landen" und "auf das Gesicht fallen": Aus medizinischer Sicht das Gleiche, aber das damit verbundene Bild ist anders.

@Cerulean : Ich habe meine Antwort aktualisiert. Vielleicht passt sie jetzt besser.

Auf dem Gesicht landet aber, glücklicherweise, kein Mensch, sondern eine Fliege. Letzteres lässt sich verschmerzen. (2x im Update).

@userunknown : Ja, Deutsch ist da mehrdeutig. Umgangssprachlich wird "auf dem Gesicht landen" auch im Sinn von "auf das Gesicht fallen" verwendet, und das passiert leider, wie ich aus  leidfaller Erfahrung sagen kann. Abhängig von der Region sagt man dazu alternativ auch "auf das Gesicht fliegen".

In der Frage ging es aber nicht um einen Menschen, der auf seinem Gesicht landet, sondern um eine Fliege, die - auch nicht auf ihrem Gesicht - sondern auf dem des Muttersprachlers landet, da ist in der Frage keine derartige Doppeldeutigkeit.

@userunknown : Oh, wie konnte ich nur die blöde Fliege übersehen. Ja, also dann doch wie ein Flugzeug auf dem Flughafen....


Eine Fliege ist auf meinem Gesicht gelandet.
Eine Fliege ist auf mein Gesicht gelandet.

Das hat weniger mit Verben der Bewegung (genauer: eigentlich überhaupt nicht mit den verwendeten Verben) zu tun, sondern mit einer Funktion des Dativs bzw. Akkusativs. Im Falle von Bewegungen beschreibt der Dativ einen Ort, der Akkusativ eine Richtung. Deshalb etwa:

Ich gehe im Park. (Ort, deshalb Dativ)
Ich gehe in den Park. (Richtung, deshalb Akkusativ)

Im ersten Fall bewegt man sich innerhalb des Parks und "Park" ist der Ort, an dem die Bewegung stattfindet. Im zweiten Fall ist "der Park" zwar auch ein Ort, aber das Gehen findet in Richtung auf den Park zu statt, es wird also eine Richtung beschrieben.
Der Grund dafür ist, daß, historisch, der Dativ (über den Umweg des lateinischen Ablativs) die Funktionen des Lokativs (Frage: wo?) übernommen hat, während der Akkusativ Funktionen des Lativs (also eines Falls, der die Richtung einer Bewegung ausdrückt) ausübt. Zum Beispiel (Latein, "Nach Rom gehen."):

Romam ire.

